# Function to change icon in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a function that is called in jquery mobile that changes the text on a button however I also want to change the icon. The function which changes the text is within an on click function already and the text changes well however I want to change the icon also. The code I use is below.

```
function setPauseState(paused) {
if (paused) 
{
    $("#playSong .ui-btn-text").text("Play");


} 
else 
{
    $("#playSong .ui-btn-text").text("Pause");

}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a link to an article outlining exactly what you want to do
http://jsimapps.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/jquery-mobile-programatically-changing-and-refreshing-button-icons/

```
$("#playSong .ui-btn-text").data('icon', 'check');
```

Icon list is

- Left arrow – “ui-icon-arrow-l”
- Right arrow – “ui-icon-arrow-r”
- Up arrow – “ui-icon-arrow-u”
- Down arrow – “ui-icon-arrow-d”
- Delete –“ui-icon-delete”
- Plus – “ui-icon-plus”
- Minus – “ui-icon-minus”
- Check – “ui-icon-check”
- Gear – “ui-icon-gear”
- Refresh – “data-iconrefresh”
- Forward – “ui-icon-forward”
- Back – “ui-icon-back”
- Grid – “ui-icon-grid”
- Star – “ui-icon-star"
- Alert – “ui-icon-alert”
- Info – “ui-icon-info”
- Home – “ui-icon-home”
- Search – “ui-icon-search”

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes as the answer does exactly what the OP asked for (in addition to listing the other icon choices).
It is jQuery instead of jQuery mobile but not sure how that would be an issue especially since the original question was asked with jQuery code

Answer (score 2):

You should use predefined jQuery Mobile function, everything else is just unnecessary coding:

```
$( "a" ).buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/4fqaK/

Official documentation :http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#option-icon